# VXLAN interface disappears

Tags: centos, network-interface, systemd-networkd

I have a CentOS 7 server with a VXLAN interface connected to a bridge.  The server is using the network service.  NetworkManager is not installed.  This `/sbin/ifup-local` script sets up the VXLAN interface after the bridge is up.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set up VXLAN once cloudbr0 is available.
if [[ "$1" == "cloudbr0" ]]
then
  ip link add vxlan100 type vxlan id 100 dstport 4789 group "240.10.11.1" dev "eth0"
  brctl addif cloudbr0 vxlan100
  ip link set up dev vxlan100
fi
```

It works for a while, then the VXLAN interface disappears.  I need help figuring out the cause and fix.  I see this in `/var/log/messages`.

```
Mar  7 18:20:37 cloudstack-worker-4 kernel: brvxlan100-100: port 2(vnet0) entered disabled state
Mar  7 18:20:37 cloudstack-worker-4 kernel: device vnet0 left promiscuous mode
Mar  7 18:20:37 cloudstack-worker-4 kernel: brvxlan100-100: port 2(vnet0) entered disabled state
Mar  7 18:20:37 cloudstack-worker-4 libvirtd: 2022-03-07 18:20:37.544+0000: 85757: error : qemuMonitorIO:718 : internal error: End of file from qemu monitor
Mar  7 18:20:37 cloudstack-worker-4 kvm: 0 guests now active
Mar  7 18:20:37 cloudstack-worker-4 systemd-machined: Machine qemu-5-i-2-34-VM terminated.
Mar  7 18:20:38 cloudstack-worker-4 java: libvirt: QEMU Driver error : Domain not found: no domain with matching uuid '32a413eb-7d54-4b63-bcea-4354c9649db9' (i-2-34-VM)
Mar  7 18:20:38 cloudstack-worker-4 java: WARN  [kvm.resource.LibvirtKvmAgentHook] (agentRequest-Handler-5:) (logid:e71a1258) Groovy script '/etc/cloudstack/agent/hooks/libvirt-vm-state-change.groovy' is not available. Transformations will not be applied.
Mar  7 18:20:38 cloudstack-worker-4 java: WARN  [kvm.resource.LibvirtKvmAgentHook] (agentRequest-Handler-5:) (logid:e71a1258) Groovy scripting engine is not initialized. Data transformation skipped.
Mar  7 18:20:38 cloudstack-worker-4 kernel: cloudbr0: port 2(vxlan100) entered disabled state
Mar  7 18:20:38 cloudstack-worker-4 kernel: device vxlan100 left promiscuous mode
Mar  7 18:20:38 cloudstack-worker-4 kernel: brvxlan100-100: port 1(vxlan100.100) entered disabled state
Mar  7 18:20:38 cloudstack-worker-4 kernel: brvxlan100-100: port 1(vxlan100.100) entered disabled state
Mar  7 18:20:39 cloudstack-worker-4 ntpd[83942]: Deleting interface #23 brvxlan100-100, fe80::4890:56ff:fe85:3cb3#123, interface stats: received=0, sent=0, dropped=0, active_time=571 secs
Mar  7 18:20:39 cloudstack-worker-4 ntpd[83942]: Deleting interface #22 vnet0, fe80::fc00:6bff:fe5b:1#123, interface stats: received=0, sent=0, dropped=0, active_time=571 secs
Mar  7 18:20:39 cloudstack-worker-4 ntpd[83942]: Deleting interface #21 vxlan100.100, fe80::8c5:cff:fec1:2025#123, interface stats: received=0, sent=0, dropped=0, active_time=571 secs
Mar  7 18:20:39 cloudstack-worker-4 ntpd[83942]: Deleting interface #14 vxlan100.179, fe80::8c5:cff:fec1:2025#123, interface stats: received=0, sent=0, dropped=0, active_time=1274 secs
Mar  7 18:20:39 cloudstack-worker-4 ntpd[83942]: Deleting interface #7 vxlan100, fe80::8c5:cff:fec1:2025#123, interface stats: received=0, sent=0, dropped=0, active_time=264643 secs
Mar  7 18:36:08 cloudstack-worker-4 java: INFO  [cloud.agent.Agent] (Agent-Handler-2:) (logid:6fdfda4a) Lost connection to host: 10.11.0.2. Attempting reconnection while we still have 0 commands in progress.
Mar  7 18:36:08 cloudstack-worker-4 java: INFO  [utils.nio.NioClient] (Agent-Handler-2:) (logid:6fdfda4a) NioClient connection closed
Mar  7 18:36:08 cloudstack-worker-4 java: INFO  [cloud.agent.Agent] (Agent-Handler-2:) (logid:6fdfda4a) Reconnecting to host:10.11.0.2
Mar  7 18:36:08 cloudstack-worker-4 java: INFO  [utils.nio.NioClient] (Agent-Handler-2:) (logid:6fdfda4a) Connecting to 10.11.0.2:8250
Mar  7 18:36:11 cloudstack-worker-4 java: ERROR [utils.nio.NioConnection] (Agent-Handler-2:) (logid:6fdfda4a) Unable to initialize the threads.
Mar  7 18:36:11 cloudstack-worker-4 java: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
```

Running `systemctl status network` shows that the network service has a long uptime (much longer than the time since the interface disappeared).  `systemctl restart network` successfully brings the missing interface back into existence.  Then after some time, the interface disappears again.

Any idea why the interface is disappearing?  The other interfaces keep working.  Is there a more reliable way to configure the interface?

UPDATE 1

Output from `ip link` after the interface disappears:

```
[centos@cloudstack-worker-3 ~]$ ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9001 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0e:e1:87:a2:92:db brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: ethdummy0: <BROADCAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master cloudbr0 state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 8a:9d:8a:91:9c:6e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
8: cloud0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
23: cloudbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 8a:9d:8a:91:9c:6e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Output from `ip link` after `systemctl restart network` brings the interface back:

```
[root@cloudstack-worker-3 centos]# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9001 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0e:e1:87:a2:92:db brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.10.67.48/18 brd 10.10.127.255 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 2361sec preferred_lft 2361sec
    inet6 fe80::ce1:87ff:fea2:92db/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: ethdummy0: <BROADCAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master cloudbr0 state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 8a:9d:8a:91:9c:6e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
8: cloud0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 169.254.0.1/16 scope global cloud0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::248d:90ff:fe51:1fa1/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
23: cloudbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 6a:bb:e5:cb:8a:b1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.11.0.13/16 brd 10.11.255.255 scope global cloudbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::889d:8aff:fe91:9c6e/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
30: vxlan100: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 8951 qdisc noqueue master cloudbr0 state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 6a:bb:e5:cb:8a:b1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::68bb:e5ff:fecb:8ab1/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

UPDATE 2

I ran `ip -ts monitor link` for a while, and there was a lot of activity around the time the interface disappeared.  (`/var/log/messages` shows ntpd detecting the deleted interface at 17:20:21.)

```
[root@cloudstack-worker-3 centos]# ip -ts monitor link
[2022-03-08T17:12:06.165185] 30: vxlan100: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 8951 qdisc noqueue master cloudbr0 state UNKNOWN group default
    link/ether 6a:bb:e5:cb:8a:b1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:12:06.165394] 31: vxlan100.100@vxlan100: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 8951 qdisc noop state DOWN group default
    link/ether 6a:bb:e5:cb:8a:b1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:12:06.165812] 31: vxlan100.100@vxlan100: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 8951 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 6a:bb:e5:cb:8a:b1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:12:06.167814] 32: brvxlan100-100: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default
    link/ether ea:26:7d:91:78:ff brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:12:06.168344] 32: brvxlan100-100: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default
    link/ether ea:26:7d:91:78:ff brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:12:06.170981] 31: vxlan100.100@vxlan100: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 8951 qdisc noqueue master brvxlan100-100 state UP group default
    link/ether 6a:bb:e5:cb:8a:b1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:12:06.171376] 30: vxlan100: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 8951 qdisc noqueue master cloudbr0 state UNKNOWN group default
    link/ether 6a:bb:e5:cb:8a:b1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:12:06.171414] 31: vxlan100.100@vxlan100: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 8951 qdisc noqueue master brvxlan100-100 state UP group default
    link/ether 6a:bb:e5:cb:8a:b1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:12:06.171459] 32: brvxlan100-100: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default
    link/ether ea:26:7d:91:78:ff brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:12:06.172330] 31: vxlan100.100@vxlan100: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 8951 master brvxlan100-100 state UP
    link/ether 6a:bb:e5:cb:8a:b1
[2022-03-08T17:12:06.172339] 31: vxlan100.100@vxlan100: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 8951 master brvxlan100-100 state UP
    link/ether 6a:bb:e5:cb:8a:b1
[2022-03-08T17:12:06.172345] 31: vxlan100.100@vxlan100: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 8951 master brvxlan100-100 state UP
    link/ether 6a:bb:e5:cb:8a:b1
[2022-03-08T17:12:06.172372] 32: brvxlan100-100: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default
    link/ether 6a:bb:e5:cb:8a:b1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:12:06.172421] 32: brvxlan100-100: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 8951 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default
    link/ether 6a:bb:e5:cb:8a:b1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:12:06.209537] 33: vnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:4f:a5:47:6e:c9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:12:06.209863] 33: vnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default
    link/ether fe:00:61:80:00:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:12:06.209874] 33: vnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 8951 qdisc noop state DOWN group default
    link/ether fe:00:61:80:00:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:12:06.210667] 33: vnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 8951 qdisc noop master brvxlan100-100 state DOWN group default
    link/ether fe:00:61:80:00:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:12:06.211017] 33: vnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 8951 qdisc noop master brvxlan100-100 state DOWN group default
    link/ether fe:00:61:80:00:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:12:06.211096] 32: brvxlan100-100: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 8951 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default
    link/ether 6a:bb:e5:cb:8a:b1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:12:06.211113] 33: vnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 8951 master brvxlan100-100 state DOWN
    link/ether fe:00:61:80:00:02
[2022-03-08T17:12:06.211176] 33: vnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 8951 qdisc pfifo_fast master brvxlan100-100 state UNKNOWN group default
    link/ether fe:00:61:80:00:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:12:06.212034] 33: vnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 8951 master brvxlan100-100 state UNKNOWN
    link/ether fe:00:61:80:00:02
[2022-03-08T17:12:06.212066] 33: vnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 8951 master brvxlan100-100 state UNKNOWN
    link/ether fe:00:61:80:00:02
[2022-03-08T17:12:06.212073] 33: vnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 8951 master brvxlan100-100 state UNKNOWN
    link/ether fe:00:61:80:00:02
[2022-03-08T17:12:06.234242] 34: vnet1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default
    link/ether 36:3d:41:4e:01:07 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:12:06.234316] 34: vnet1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default
    link/ether fe:00:a9:fe:1f:0a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:12:06.235157] 34: vnet1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop master cloud0 state DOWN group default
    link/ether fe:00:a9:fe:1f:0a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:12:06.235509] 34: vnet1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop master cloud0 state DOWN group default
    link/ether fe:00:a9:fe:1f:0a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:12:06.235551] 8: cloud0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:12:06.235559] 34: vnet1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 master cloud0 state DOWN
    link/ether fe:00:a9:fe:1f:0a
[2022-03-08T17:12:06.235603] 8: cloud0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether fe:00:a9:fe:1f:0a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:12:06.235685] 34: vnet1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master cloud0 state UNKNOWN group default
    link/ether fe:00:a9:fe:1f:0a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:12:06.236450] 34: vnet1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 master cloud0 state UNKNOWN
    link/ether fe:00:a9:fe:1f:0a
[2022-03-08T17:12:06.236458] 34: vnet1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 master cloud0 state UNKNOWN
    link/ether fe:00:a9:fe:1f:0a
[2022-03-08T17:12:06.236464] 34: vnet1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 master cloud0 state UNKNOWN
    link/ether fe:00:a9:fe:1f:0a
[2022-03-08T17:12:06.236759] 35: vnet2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default
    link/ether ee:73:d0:55:96:b8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:12:06.236818] 35: vnet2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default
    link/ether fe:00:ed:00:01:c9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:12:06.237680] 35: vnet2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop master cloudbr0 state DOWN group default
    link/ether fe:00:ed:00:01:c9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:12:06.238113] 35: vnet2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop master cloudbr0 state DOWN group default
    link/ether fe:00:ed:00:01:c9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:12:06.238121] 35: vnet2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 master cloudbr0 state DOWN
    link/ether fe:00:ed:00:01:c9
[2022-03-08T17:12:06.238205] 35: vnet2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master cloudbr0 state UNKNOWN group default
    link/ether fe:00:ed:00:01:c9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:12:06.238997] 35: vnet2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 master cloudbr0 state UNKNOWN
    link/ether fe:00:ed:00:01:c9
[2022-03-08T17:12:06.239008] 35: vnet2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 master cloudbr0 state UNKNOWN
    link/ether fe:00:ed:00:01:c9
[2022-03-08T17:12:06.239013] 35: vnet2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 master cloudbr0 state UNKNOWN
    link/ether fe:00:ed:00:01:c9
[2022-03-08T17:12:06.239128] 8: cloud0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether fe:00:a9:fe:1f:0a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:12:06.342461] 33: vnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 8951 qdisc htb master brvxlan100-100 state UNKNOWN group default
    link/ether fe:00:61:80:00:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:12:06.342563] 32: brvxlan100-100: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 8951 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default
    link/ether 6a:bb:e5:cb:8a:b1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:12:06.342624] 33: vnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 8951 qdisc htb master brvxlan100-100 state UNKNOWN group default
    link/ether fe:00:61:80:00:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:12:06.342660] 32: brvxlan100-100: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 8951 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default
    link/ether 6a:bb:e5:cb:8a:b1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:12:06.342893] 34: vnet1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master cloud0 state UNKNOWN group default
    link/ether fe:00:a9:fe:1f:0a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:12:06.342959] 8: cloud0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether fe:00:a9:fe:1f:0a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:12:06.343006] 34: vnet1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master cloud0 state UNKNOWN group default
    link/ether fe:00:a9:fe:1f:0a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:12:06.343042] 8: cloud0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether fe:00:a9:fe:1f:0a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:12:06.343255] 35: vnet2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc htb master cloudbr0 state UNKNOWN group default
    link/ether fe:00:ed:00:01:c9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:12:06.343314] 35: vnet2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc htb master cloudbr0 state UNKNOWN group default
    link/ether fe:00:ed:00:01:c9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:12:07.166770] 32: brvxlan100-100: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 8951 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 6a:bb:e5:cb:8a:b1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:12:09.839987] 33: vnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 8951 qdisc htb master brvxlan100-100 state UNKNOWN group default
    link/ether fe:00:61:80:00:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:12:09.840016] 32: brvxlan100-100: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 8951 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 6a:bb:e5:cb:8a:b1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:12:09.848776] 34: vnet1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master cloud0 state UNKNOWN group default
    link/ether fe:00:a9:fe:1f:0a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:12:09.848821] 8: cloud0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether fe:00:a9:fe:1f:0a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:12:09.852466] 35: vnet2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc htb master cloudbr0 state UNKNOWN group default
    link/ether fe:00:ed:00:01:c9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:12:11.254594] 35: vnet2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 master cloudbr0 state UNKNOWN
    link/ether fe:00:ed:00:01:c9
[2022-03-08T17:12:21.174674] 31: vxlan100.100@vxlan100: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 8951 master brvxlan100-100 state UP
    link/ether 6a:bb:e5:cb:8a:b1
[2022-03-08T17:12:21.238653] 34: vnet1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 master cloud0 state UNKNOWN
    link/ether fe:00:a9:fe:1f:0a
[2022-03-08T17:12:21.239591] 33: vnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 8951 master brvxlan100-100 state UNKNOWN
    link/ether fe:00:61:80:00:02
[2022-03-08T17:20:19.215787] 33: vnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 8951 qdisc htb master brvxlan100-100 state DOWN group default
    link/ether fe:00:61:80:00:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:20:19.216347] 33: vnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 8951 master brvxlan100-100 state DOWN
    link/ether fe:00:61:80:00:02
[2022-03-08T17:20:19.216361] 33: vnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 8951 master brvxlan100-100 state DOWN
    link/ether fe:00:61:80:00:02
[2022-03-08T17:20:19.218506] 33: vnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 8951 master brvxlan100-100 state DOWN
    link/ether fe:00:61:80:00:02
[2022-03-08T17:20:19.218518] Deleted 33: vnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 8951 master brvxlan100-100 state DOWN
    link/ether fe:00:61:80:00:02
[2022-03-08T17:20:19.223039] 32: brvxlan100-100: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 8951 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 6a:bb:e5:cb:8a:b1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:20:19.223210] Deleted 33: vnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 8951 qdisc noop state DOWN group default
    link/ether fe:00:61:80:00:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:20:19.238916] 34: vnet1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master cloud0 state DOWN group default
    link/ether fe:00:a9:fe:1f:0a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:20:19.239404] 34: vnet1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 master cloud0 state DOWN
    link/ether fe:00:a9:fe:1f:0a
[2022-03-08T17:20:19.239450] 34: vnet1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 master cloud0 state DOWN
    link/ether fe:00:a9:fe:1f:0a
[2022-03-08T17:20:19.241524] 34: vnet1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 master cloud0 state DOWN
    link/ether fe:00:a9:fe:1f:0a
[2022-03-08T17:20:19.241606] Deleted 34: vnet1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 master cloud0 state DOWN
    link/ether fe:00:a9:fe:1f:0a
[2022-03-08T17:20:19.248933] 8: cloud0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:20:19.249089] 8: cloud0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:20:19.249240] Deleted 34: vnet1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default
    link/ether fe:00:a9:fe:1f:0a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:20:19.260921] 35: vnet2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc htb master cloudbr0 state DOWN group default
    link/ether fe:00:ed:00:01:c9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:20:19.261455] 35: vnet2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 master cloudbr0 state DOWN
    link/ether fe:00:ed:00:01:c9
[2022-03-08T17:20:19.261469] 35: vnet2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 master cloudbr0 state DOWN
    link/ether fe:00:ed:00:01:c9
[2022-03-08T17:20:19.263556] 35: vnet2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 master cloudbr0 state DOWN
    link/ether fe:00:ed:00:01:c9
[2022-03-08T17:20:19.263585] Deleted 35: vnet2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 master cloudbr0 state DOWN
    link/ether fe:00:ed:00:01:c9
[2022-03-08T17:20:19.268967] Deleted 35: vnet2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default
    link/ether fe:00:ed:00:01:c9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:20:20.226898] 8: cloud0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:20:20.310747] 30: vxlan100: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 8951 qdisc noqueue master cloudbr0 state UNKNOWN group default
    link/ether 6a:bb:e5:cb:8a:b1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:20:20.311100] 30: vxlan100: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 8951 master cloudbr0 state UNKNOWN
    link/ether 6a:bb:e5:cb:8a:b1
[2022-03-08T17:20:20.311112] Deleted 30: vxlan100: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 8951 master cloudbr0 state UNKNOWN
    link/ether 6a:bb:e5:cb:8a:b1
[2022-03-08T17:20:20.317679] 30: vxlan100: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 8951 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default
    link/ether 6a:bb:e5:cb:8a:b1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:20:20.317793] 23: cloudbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 8a:9d:8a:91:9c:6e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:20:20.317844] 23: cloudbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 8a:9d:8a:91:9c:6e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:20:20.318482] 30: vxlan100: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 8951 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 6a:bb:e5:cb:8a:b1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:20:20.320254] 30: vxlan100: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 8951 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 6a:bb:e5:cb:8a:b1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:20:20.320311] 31: vxlan100.100@vxlan100: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,ALLMULTI,PROMISC,M-DOWN> mtu 8951 qdisc noqueue master brvxlan100-100 state DOWN group default
    link/ether 6a:bb:e5:cb:8a:b1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:20:20.320843] 31: vxlan100.100@vxlan100: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,ALLMULTI,PROMISC,M-DOWN> mtu 8951 master brvxlan100-100 state DOWN
    link/ether 6a:bb:e5:cb:8a:b1
[2022-03-08T17:20:20.320852] 31: vxlan100.100@vxlan100: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,ALLMULTI,PROMISC,M-DOWN> mtu 8951 master brvxlan100-100 state DOWN
    link/ether 6a:bb:e5:cb:8a:b1
[2022-03-08T17:20:20.322764] 31: vxlan100.100@vxlan100: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,ALLMULTI,PROMISC,M-DOWN> mtu 8951 master brvxlan100-100 state DOWN
    link/ether 6a:bb:e5:cb:8a:b1
[2022-03-08T17:20:20.322784] Deleted 31: vxlan100.100@vxlan100: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,ALLMULTI,PROMISC,M-DOWN> mtu 8951 master brvxlan100-100 state DOWN
    link/ether 6a:bb:e5:cb:8a:b1
[2022-03-08T17:20:20.331412] 32: brvxlan100-100: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 6a:bb:e5:cb:8a:b1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:20:20.331502] 32: brvxlan100-100: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:20:20.331546] 32: brvxlan100-100: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:20:20.331561] Deleted 31: vxlan100.100@vxlan100: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,ALLMULTI,PROMISC,M-DOWN> mtu 8951 qdisc noop state DOWN group default
    link/ether 6a:bb:e5:cb:8a:b1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:20:20.332299] Deleted 30: vxlan100: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 8951 qdisc noop state DOWN group default
    link/ether 6a:bb:e5:cb:8a:b1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:20:20.347065] 32: brvxlan100-100: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[2022-03-08T17:20:20.356653] Deleted 32: brvxlan100-100: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default
    link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: Did it really disappear? What's the output of `ip link` when the network doesn't work anymore? You can track this for sure by keeping this (never ending) command running: `ip -ts monitor link` . In particular, does eth0 disappear too (maybe in an other namespace)?

Comment: @A.B Yes, it totally disappears.  It's not listed in the output from `ip link`.  The other interfaces (including eth0 and cloudbr0) are still listed in the output.  I'll add that info to the question.

Comment: I'll monitor using `ip -ts monitor link` for a while and see what shows up.

Comment: @A.B I updated the question with the monitor output.  It shows the interface being deleted. `[2022-03-08T17:20:20.332299] Deleted 30: vxlan100: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 8951 qdisc noop state DOWN group default
    link/ether 6a:bb:e5:cb:8a:b1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff`

Comment: I guess you could cross-check this with other logs from various other tools involved in networking to know which one could have done this.

Comment: @A.B The only other file under `/var/log` that includes the interface name is `/var/log/audit/audit.log`.  It says `type=ANOM_PROMISCUOUS msg=audit(1646760020.317:1872): dev=vxlan100 prom=0 old_prom=256 auid=4294967295 uid=0 gid=0 ses=4294967295`.  No idea what that means.

Comment: Looks like my idea leads nowhere: there is a Deleted entry but it's followed by further entries where vxlan0 with index 30 exists/reappears, and I don't know what to do about it.

Comment: I noticed that the interface is being deleted about the same time that CloudStack shuts down a VM and deletes the VM's interfaces.  So, knowing that CloudStack sometimes uses pattern matching on interface names, I renamed the interface from vxlan100 to ethvxlan0.  It's been stable since then, but I want to give it more time to make sure it's actually fixed.  This could be a CloudStack bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never saw this issue when the server was idle.  I also noticed in `/var/log/messages` that the vxlan100 interface was always being deleted about the same time that CloudStack shut down a VM and deleted the associated network interfaces. Knowing that CloudStack sometimes uses pattern matching on interface names, I renamed the interface from vxlan100 to ethvxlan0. It's been stable since then.

When CloudStack is binding its API to a network interface, it only uses interfaces with names that match eth*, bond*, team*, vlan*, em*, p*p*, ens*, eno*, enp*, or enx*.  I wonder if it has a cleanup routine that deletes all interfaces that don't match one of those patterns?

The name vxlan100 never appeared in the CloudStack logs.  I don't have proof that this is a CloudStack bug, but it's my best guess for now.